# Can "Snap" packages use the GPU?

Tags: games, snap, gpu

Pretty straightforward - can "Snap" packages use the dedicated (NVIDIA) GPU in my laptop?

For example, if I download a game via a "Snap" package (e.g. "SuperTuxKart"), will it use the GPU, or will I need to download the "traditional" package instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, snap package can use the GPU.
To check whether a snap package has access to GPU acceleration, run the following command. Assuming you want to check for *chromium*, you can see that the snap package has been configured to use GPU acceleration.

```
$ snap connections chromium
...
opengl                    chromium:opengl                    :opengl                         -
...
$
```

For the case of chromium, you can test with WebGL demo pages.