# 22.04: Snap apps use SW emulation instead of GPU acceleration on AMD RDNA 3

Tags: graphics

Apps in Snap have no GPU acceleration with Radeon 7900 XTX. This causes very slow window redrawing in LibreOffice, and Google Maps in Firefox refuse to enable the 3D view.

I have the latest Mesa installed, which may be recommended for such a recent GPU, and indeed all non-snap apps do have GPU acceleration.

How do I enable GPU acceleration for apps in Snap to make them use Mesa that's installed in the system?

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274383/can-snap-packages-use-the-gpu